# How to prevent a Spring Boot application from instantiating a JDBC datasource during tests?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I've recently added JPA to my application for a single database request. Since then the tests are failing:
`java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext`

[...]

`Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer'`

My understanding here is that during the test run Spring Boot tries to initialize the database connection, but I'm not interested in doing any tests on the added db request. How can I stop this behaviour?

Comment: Add H2 for an in-memory database or stop using `@SpringBootTest` for simple testcases (which is whatyou are probably doing, without knowing the implications of this).

Comment: H2: Don't want to add any db tests. @SpringBootTest: What would be an alternative?

Comment: You don't need to but H2 will be created at startup of your test. This is what you need when writing tests with `@SpringBootTest` it will bootstrap a full application. If you don't want that don't use `@SpringBootTest` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get this error as you are probably abusing `@SpringBootTest` to do tests for services with using `@MockBean` to inject/create mocks for dependencies/repositories. `@SpringBootTest` is mainly intended for writing integration tests for the whole application not to test 1 single service.

The short answer is don't. Either use one of the sliced tests for that or just write a simple unit test (instantiate the service yourself and create mocks using Mockito yourself and inject, don't abuse `@SpringBootTest` for that).

If you really want to continue on this way the easiest solution is to add H2 as a test dependency so you have an in-memory database created for you when running tests. You don't use it but it is needed to start the application.

Another option would be to mock the `DataSource` in an `@TestConfiguration`. Problem is you would need to mock a whole lot of methods and classes as well and you are basically mocking so much you have mocked a stub of a datasource implementation.